# time complexity: check that all elements of at least one row or column in a matrix are equal

Tags: ruby, matrix, time-complexity

My function should return true or false depending on if there exists at least one row or column in a square matrix whose elements are all equal to each other.

I solved the problem already, but I believe the time complexity is O(n^2), because I solved it using nested loops. I'd like to take my solution a step further and try to do better. I'd appreciate any tips or hints!

```
def any_same_lines?(arr)
    # return true if any row's elements are all the same
    return true if arr.any? {|row| row.all? { |ele| ele == row[0] } }

    # return true if any column's elements are all the same
    k = 0
    while k < arr.length
        return true if arr.all? { |row| row[k] == arr[0][k] }
        k += 1
    end
    false
end
```

Comment: The input is restricted to square matrices only

Comment: When clarifying a question you should edit the question rather than elaborating in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your algorithm, you're look at each cell twice

1. Once in the first loop (for each row)
2. Once in the second loop (for each column)

So your complexity is O(2N), which is ~ O(N).

So you're not really going to do better than this in a worst-case. Additionally, you're also already bailing out early in case of differences (with `.all?` and `.any?`), so your practical performance will depend on the data but should be pretty good.

I expect there's further room to optimize (like visiting each node once instead of twice) but not from a big-o perspective.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My confusion comes from this part: when I'm checking rows, aren't I checking (in the worst case) N elements of each row, N times (1 time per row)? Why would it be additive rather than multiplicative?

Comment: When thinking about algorithmic complexity you need to specify what N means. We could say that we have N rows and M columns. If that's how we define it, then you're correct that complexity would be: `O (N*M)`. But since you just used "N" the common assumption is going to be that "N" is the total size of the input, in this case I would expect N = # of cells in the array.

Comment: The "common assumption" certainly was not mine. When the OP refers to a time-complexity of `O(n^2)`, taken with his/her comment on the question, I find it difficult to understand how one can avoid the conclusion that the array contains `n` `n`-element arrays. Moreover, "total size of the input" is a vague concept when performing big-O calculations.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Caveat that I took my algorithms classes ~15 years ago and since then have only dealt with big-o as it relates to application development... so I don't consider myself an expert. Also agree it's critical to define `n` to avoid any confusion. That having been said, i'd expect running a "N^2" algorithm on a 2-dimensional array with (x * y) unique elements would take (x * y)^2 time. It's equivalent to a 1-dimensional array with x * y unique elements.